# SS2.0 : Debugging a Map/Reduce

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Anyone ever debug a Map/Reduce?

I hit the 'Debug' on the Map/Reduce deployment record ... it takes me to the debugger and hangs on 'Waiting for User Action"

What 'action' do I need to take?

Comment: Have you tried 'Save and Execute' in deployment ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the best debugger is to just use the script log. 
log.debug(...)

Write your getInfo state during debugging to only return a small subset of results. You can use getRange for doing that. Just be aware that the map context.values JSON changes the join order on your results (field.join vs join.field) compared to a loaded search.

You might also find this Chrome extension useful:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-html-script-note/lipldhgjkmfhamocfcdijcdgjcikcbkk

Answer (score 0):

Go to the script deployment and hit edit.  Then select "Save and Execute".

The debugger is waiting for you to trigger the map reduce script.  Let me know if this help.